# Rounding Values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, decimal, rounding

I'm looking to round values like below

```
10.5  -> 11.00
28.35 -> 28.50
17.85 -> 18.00
```

Condition is if value < 50 then round to .50 else it will round to 1.

How can i apply in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
SELECT
    value AS old_value,
    CASE WHEN value < 50
         THEN CEILING(value*2) / 2
         ELSE CEILING(value) END AS new_value
FROM yourTable;
```

After reviewing your comment, I actually stand by the logic in this query.  Here are the results I generated while testing:

[image: screen shot of test data]

### Demo

Note that `10.5` maps to itself, not to `11.0`.  The reason for this is that you have defined the `0.5` level as a stop gap for rounding.  It makes no sense that other numbers should round to the nearest `0.5,` and stop there, but `10.5` should keep going to `11.0`.

Comment: I have tried the logic it giving this result for ex 2.25 > 3 it should give  2.50 thanks.

Comment: +1, nice solution. But why do you need `case` there? Always should be `CEILING(value*2) / 2`. For example, for 50.3 will return wrong value

Comment: @uzi Read the question: `Condition is if value < 50 then round to .50 else it will round to 1.` ... numbers greater than 50 take the ceiling.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I missed that part